# Numerically Simulating a Simple Differential Equation: RC Circuit

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I need to learn to simulate a differential equation in Mathematica.  The differential equation that I need to simulate is complicated, without an analytical solution. However, I am brand new to Mathematica.  I thought it would be a simple matter to start by simulating the charging of an RC circuit, but even though I understand the equations, I can't figure out where to start in the Mathematica simulation.

Here's what I want to do:
From time $t=0$ until time $t=t_o$, the input voltage $V_{in}=0$ and hence the current $I(t)=0$.  At time $t_o$, the voltage $V_{in}$ is switched on. After the voltage is on, the capacitor $C$ charges. The differential equation and its solution are:

$$\frac{dI(t)}{dt}RC+I(t)=0$$

For the time $t<t_o$, $I(t)=0$ and $V_{in}(t)=0$. For the time $t>t_O$,

$$I(t)=A e^{-(t-t_o)/RC}$$

Where $A$ is a constant to be determined from initial conditions. For the time $t=t_o$, voltage $I(t_o)=A=\frac{V_o}{R}$ where $V_{in}(t_o)=V_o$ is the input voltage at $t_o$, and $R$ is the resistance of the circuit.

So here's what I want to do: The input will be the differential equation $\frac{dI(t)}{dt}RC+I(t)=0$ and a current $I(t)=\frac{V_o}{R}H(t-t_o)$, where $H(t-t_o)$ is the Heaviside step function with the step at $t=t_o$.  The output will be a graph showing the behavior of $I(t)$ with respect to time.

I can do this:

```
RC = 4

Vin = 2

s = NDSolve[{It'[t] == -(1/RC) It[t], It[0] == Vin}, It, {t, 0, 30}]

Plot[Evaluate[It[t] /. s], {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

But don't know how to get the step function in there. Please help!

Edit: I assume that if I can put the Heaviside in there, a square pulse, a square wave, and ramp, etc can be done as well. Is this wrong?

Comment: why do you need a step function for? Since solution to ODE, which is the current is zero before $t_0$ for any $t_0$ any way.  You could always shift the solution to right afterwords if you want. But may be I am missing something about your description.

Comment: Good Question.  Eventually, I will need to turn the system on and off, and watch the response.  So once I can add a step, I assume it can be adapted to a square wave or something like that.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps it's overshooting, but I like this way:

```
RC = 4
Vin = 2
s = NDSolve[{It'[t] + (1/RC) It[t] == q[t], It[0] == 0, q[0] == 0, 
            WhenEvent[t == 10, q[t] -> 1]}, It, {t, 0, 30}, 
            DiscreteVariables -> q]

Plot[Evaluate[It[t] /. s], {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: WhenEvent is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The step function comes on the right-hand side:

```
i[t] /. NDSolve[{i'[t]/c + r i[t] == UnitStep[t], 
 i[0] == 0} /. {c -> 1, r -> 4}, i[t], {t, 0, 5}];
```

The plot shows the current as the capacitor is being charged:

```
Plot[%, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

You can change the input to something else, for example a `SquareWave` input shows the capacitor being charged and discharged:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just start integrating at $t_0$ instead of $0$.  If you are hell-bent on getting the integrator to do nothing from $0$ to $t_0$, then use the `UnitStep[]` function.

Comment: Where to use the UnitStep[]?